# How to pass Ajax from post success data to another View in asp.net MVC

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-ajax

in my `ASP.Net` `MVC` application, I make the flowing `Ajax` from post

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("Search", "Home", new AjaxOptions {OnSuccess = "OnSuccess", OnFailure = "OnFailure",HttpMethod = "POST", LoadingElementId = "loading"}))
```

to the following`Action`

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<ActionResult> Search(SearchParam searchParam) 
{
   // an Api call is made to get the desire data
   // according to searchParam, which gives the 
   // following expected result

   flightInfo = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<FlightInfo.Rootobject>(jsonString);

   return Json(new { redirectTo = Url.Action("SearchResult", "Home", flightInfo) });
}
```

now, on the `OnSuccess` function

```
 function OnSuccess(response) {
            if (response.redirectTo) {
                window.location.href = response.redirectTo;
            }
        }
```

which hit the desire `SearchResult` `Action`

```
 public ActionResult SearchResult(FlightInfo.Rootobject result)
 {
    return View(result);
 }
```

but pass `null` data on it

> On a summary, I need to render `flightInfo` data into a new `View`

- `FlightInfo.Rootobject` contains array

Any solution or suggestion in either `c#` or `jQuery` or `js` will be very helpful. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why would you do that even?! I mean seriously? Either use Ajax itself to async call the Task<ActionResult> or just do not return the data within Json and return it normally as Model in your view

Comment: This does not make sense. The whole point of making an ajax call is to stay to the same page, yet you seem to be wanting to redirect to another page. Do not use ajax

Comment: @Stephen Muecke, `flightInfo` contains lot of data and requires specific view to render, so I need a page redirect.

Comment: Yes, which is why you DO NOT use ajax.

Comment: @Valkyrie, "do not return the data within Json and return it normally as Model in your view" - an example will be very helpful

Comment: And if `flightInfo` _contains a lot of data_, then you will probably throw an exception  because of the query string limit even if you did generate the correct query string

Comment: yah, now it makes sense, I can go with `HTML from post` instead. But I wish to know is there any way out to pass the such success data into another controller view

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/167039/discussion-between-ramzan-ali-and-stephen-muecke).

Answer (score 0):

Ajax is used when you need to update a part of the page. In your example, you need to go to another page after your form submit so you don't use the good method.

For the form you should use an `Html.BeginForm` to call your`[HttpPost] Search(SearchParam searchParam)` method.
In that method, instead of return a Json and try to make the redirection with your javascript, you should use `return RedirectToAction("SearchResult");` and put your complex object in `TempData["flightInfo"];` so you can recover it in your `SearchResult` function.

Hope it will help.

Comment: `flightInfo` is a complex object! - `new { result = flightInfo}` will never work

Comment: @Pierre-AdrienMaison, thanks for your ans, I change the form submission method to `HTML` at last